# How do I compress imported images?

Tags: php, wordpress, image-compression

I've recently imported blog posts from blogger to a wordpress site.

Google page speed is telling me these images should be losslessly compressed.

How do I go about compressing these images if they weren't uploaded by me?

I have 1000+ of these images that are attached to each post and are not part of my media.

They all have links like this http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-CRkcAeqLqFU/UUA5MUbe8MI/AAAAAAAAKcs/ZGi4LFxQ-nQ/s320/Kelly+Rowland.jpg

Here's an example page:
http://lartmagazine.co.uk/whos-loving-kelly-rowlands-new-video/

Comment: Question already asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/19696187/785207 or here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/5451597/785207

Comment: @Sparkup okay, but my images aren't part of my library and are links, does that question still apply to me?

Comment: If they are not hosted by you then there isn't very much you can do about them.

Comment: @Sparkup Well, thanks for the help but this is what I was asking. Besides, I think I've found an import plugin that copies these attachments locally.

Comment: If you decide to import them then the question has already been answered :)

Comment: @Sparkup haha, yes. If the import works then I shall go over your answer :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello to make them losslessly compressed there are few tools you can use if you dont have root right to the webhost.

PNGOptimizer - Converts into PNG other lossless image formats (BMP, GIF, TGA).

Platform: Windows

At a tiny 146KB download, PNGOptimizer is the smallest program here, so it's no real surprise that the interface is a little basic. Or that it concentrates on PNG files.

http://psydk.org/PngOptimizer

FileOptimizer
Not only can it compress JPG, GIF and PNG images, but it can also work with executable files, archives, Microsoft Office documents, PDF files, and the list goes on.

http://nikkhokkho.sourceforge.net/static.php?page=FileOptimizer

Other Way is to check your phpinfo
1) Open notepad

2) Write

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Save as info.php upload to server and see if you have mod_deflate & GZIP on

then upload to your .htaccess file

```
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # html, xml, css, and js:

 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript    application/javascript application/json

    # webfonts and svg:
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)$" >SetOutputFilter DEFLATE</FilesMatch>

  </IfModule>
```

don't forget to add above the image type i am sure that png can be done only jpegs are already compressed.

Have a great day
From: Shomron David
Hawk-Tech

Comment: aha, thanks, I already enabled and configured mod_defalte on my apache server. It was more a problem of importing the external image links. Thanks though, I literally only enabled mod_deflate early today.